# How to print all session variables currently set?

Tags: php, session

Without having to call each session variable by name, is there a way to display the content of all the session variables currently set?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

Or you can use `print_r` if you don't care about types. If you use `print_r`, you can make the second argument `TRUE` so it will return instead of echo, useful for...

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: The OP is asking about all the sessions.

Comment: @kiamlaluno You mean the sessions for every user?

Comment: The title says "How to print all sessions currently set in PHP?"; if all the OP wanted was to print the current session, then the question is wrongly written.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I think what he wanted can be derived from the question. The title seems to say he wants all sessions set for each session, however, the question body says he wants them without having to call each session by name, which I assumed would be the key in `$_SESSION`. Though he could have been referring to the hash that is assigned in the cookie, I thought the former seemed more likely.

Comment: @alex, you don't need to add `<pre>` tag when using `var_dump`; calling the function already prints that tag.

Comment: @fibriZo according to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), it won't

Comment: Sorry @alex, you're right; it has something to do with XDebug as it is pointed out here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666916/php-weird-var-dump-behavior

Comment: thank you this worked for me..<?php echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>'; ?>

Comment: @kiamlaluno I've edit the question so it's more precise in what appear to be what he really wanted to know.

Answer (score 23):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo "<h3> PHP List All Session Variables</h3>";
    foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
    echo $key." ".$val."<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: This is a better solution that prints just the content and not extra array crap.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Objects stored in the session (ie dates) don't echo.

Answer (score 5):

Not a simple way, no.

Let's say that by "active" you mean "hasn't passed the maximum lifetime" and hasn't been explicitly destroyed and that you're using the default session handler.

- First, the maximum lifetime is defined as a php.ini config and is defined in terms of the last activity on the session. So the "expiry" mechanism would have to read the content of the sessions to determine the application-defined expiry.
- Second, you'd have to manually read the sessions directory and read the files, whose format I don't even know they're in.

If you really need this, you must implement some sort of custom session handler. See [`session_set_save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

Take also in consideration that you'll have no feedback if the user just closes the browser or moves away from your site without explciitly logging out. Depending on much inactivity you consider the threshold to deem a session "inactive", the number of false positives you'll get may be very high.

Comment: The files appear to be in this format `last_active|i:1280043940;`, so with a bit of splitting, I think we could produce a list (though not accurately *active* sessions)

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me:-

`<?php echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>'; ?>`

thanks for sharing code...

```
Array
(    
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1490879962

    [user_id] => 3

    [designation_name] => Admin
    [region_name] => admin
    [territory_name] => admin
    [designation_id] => 2
    [region_id] => 1
    [territory_id] => 1
    [employee_user_id] => mosin11
)
```

Comment: This lists all $_SESSION variables nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following code.

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: the question is asking for all sessions, not just the current session

Answer (score 1):

Echo the session object as json. I like json because I have a browser extension that nicely formats json.

```php
session_start();
echo json_encode($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
echo '<pre>';var_dump($_SESSION);echo '</pre>';
// or
echo '<pre>';print_r($_SESSION);echo '</pre>';
```

**NOTE: session_start(); line is must** then only you will able to print the value $_SESSION