# Weird var_dump behavior

Tags: php, xdebug

I have the following line of code:

```
var_dump(array());
```

In one file, it outputs this:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

In the second file, it outputs this:

```
string '<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>' (length=119)
```

Any ideas what's causing this in the second file? When I view the source of the rendered markup of the second file, I see this:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'&lt;pre class=&#39;xdebug-var-dump&#39; dir=&#39;ltr&#39;&gt;&#10;&lt;b&gt;array&lt;/b&gt; &lt;i&gt;(size=0)&lt;/i&gt;&#10;  &lt;i&gt;&lt;font color=&#39;#888a85&#39;&gt;empty&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&#10;&lt;/pre&gt;'</font> <i>(length=119)</i>
</pre>
```

**UPDATE 1:** the view -> source of the first file:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var_dump()` is replaced by Xdebugs custom function, as mentioned here:

> Xdebug replaces PHP's var_dump() function for displaying variables. Xdebug's version includes different colors for different types and places limits on the amount of array elements/object properties, maximum depth and string lengths. There are a few other functions dealing with variable display as well.

http://xdebug.org/docs/display

Guess you're somehow/where implementing xdebug in your second file.

Comment: xdebug on both files. The View -> Source verifies it. Problem is that on the second file, the HTML entities are being escaped?

Comment: thanks for the update. do you've got different xdebug settings in your second file or some sort of output buffering?

Comment: Sorry, I think I know where I went wrong. I was outputting the result of a curl call, which called a script that did a var dump.