# printing session variables in php

Tags: php

How do I print these sessions using the `print_r` function. 
I'm new to php.
Theses are the sessions.

```
$studentID = $_SESSION['StudentID'];
$offeringID=$_SESSION['OfferingID'];
$email=$_SESSION['email'];
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION);` ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print all sessions currently set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331613/how-to-print-all-sessions-currently-set)

Comment: Do i write the session or the variable?

Comment: When I write `print_r($_SESSION)` its give me this error  `Use of undefined constant _SESSION - assumed '_SESSION'`

Comment: @Anubis  did you have `session_start();` on top of your page just after starting `<?php`

Comment: Thanks for the answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to clear first that session is started on top.

```
session_start();
```

then assign a value to the session. i assuming that your variables have some values. then,

```
$_SESSION['StudentID']= $studentID ;
$_SESSION['OfferingID']= $offeringID;
$_SESSION['email']=$email;
```

Now if you wants to print that session values using print_r, i am printing studentid here,

```
print_r($_SESSION['StudentID']);
```

if you wants to print full session,

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print whole session then

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

IF you want single session then

```
print_r($_SESSION['StudentID']);
```